# Definition of Frechet derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $f: U \to Y$ be a map from $U \subset X$ open, $X,Y$ Banach spaces. Then the Frechet derivative at $x_0 \in X$ [is defined as follows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative):

$f$ is called Frechet differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists a linear map $A: X \to Y$ such that the following limit is $0$:

$$ \lim_{x \to x_0}{\|f(x) - f(x_0) - A(x-x_0) \|\over \|x - x_0\|}$$

What is the role of the open subset and why is it necessary that $A$ be defined on the whole space? Concretely, is it possible to define the Frechet derivative equivalently as follows:

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map between Banach spaces. Then $f$ is Frechet differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists a linear map $A: X \to Y$ such that the following limit equals $0$:
$$ \lim_{x \to x_0}{\|f(x) - f(x_0) - A(x-x_0) \|\over \|x - x_0\|}$$

Or equivalently:

Let $X,Y$ be a Banach spaces and $U\subset X$ an open subset. Then $f: X \to Y$ is (Frechet) differentiable on $U$ if for $x_0 \in U$  there exists a linear map $A: U \to Y$ such that the following limit equals $0$:
$$ \lim_{x \to x_0}{\|f(x) - f(x_0) - A(x-x_0) \|\over \|x - x_0\|}$$

Comment: The open subset is because we don't need $f$ to be defined on the whole of $X$. 

Think back to basic first course in single variable calculus. We can have a notion of differentiable function even if $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ and is undefined outside of $(0,1)$.

Comment: That $A$ is defined over $X$ is because it is linear. If a linear map in a TVS is defined on an open set, it has a well-defined unique _linear_ extension to the rest of the vector space.

Comment: If you find this confusing, my suggestion is to go back and first review basic multivariable calculus in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (say, the second half of Rudin's _Principles of..._) and then draw the obvious analogy.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you, you are right I should learn about mutlivariable calculus.

Answer (score 1):

1. To allow functions from an open subspace of $X$ makes the definition more general, and thus applicable for cases where the given function could not be extended in a differentiable way to the whole space (simplest exaple is $x\mapsto 1/x$ which is defined only on an open subset of $X=\Bbb R$, and is differentiable there).
2. If a *linear* function $U\to Y$ is defined on an *open* subset $U$ of the Banach space $X$, then it automatically extends to the whole space by linearity.
3. However, your question might make sense: among infinite dimensional spaces there are several operators that are defined only on a dense subspace of the domain, and we might consider such '*unbounded*' operators as well in the definition.